# message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true); is working fine and marking the mail as read but Same is not updating if i am opening the mail in Gmail

Tags: java, gmail-imap

The Code is working fine and it's reading the mail and I guess it's marking the mail as read because when I run it the second time it's not reading(not printing content) it but when I open my Gmail it still shows the mail as unread.

```
Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");              
                folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
                Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
                FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
                Message[] foundMessages = folderInbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);
                for (int i = 0; i < foundMessages.length; i++) {
                    Message message = foundMessages[i];
                    if(message.getSubject().contains(keyword)&&message.getSentDate().after(maxDate)) {
                        String subject = message.getSubject();    
                        String result = "";
                        if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                            result = message.getContent().toString();
                        } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                            MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent();
                            result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
                            result=result.toString();                        
                        }                       
                        System.out.println("Content message #" + i + ": " + result);
                        **message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);**
```

Comment: If you wish to get an answer to your question, it is helpful to provide enough information for others to know what you are doing. In your code example, you are using unspecified classes (likely from some library). All I can tell you with this is to read the documentation of `setFlag(Flag, boolean)` and see if it tells you whether it immediately updates the message online, or just locally.

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The question is very open as it is, share the *minimal code* required to **reproduce** your issue. Thanks!